# How to make this table prettier?

Tags: tables

Self-explanatory title. I'm new to LaTeX and this table looks pretty ugly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccccc|} 
\hline
     &  $0$ & $\frac{\pi}{6}$      & $\frac{\pi}{4}$      & $\frac{\pi}{6}$      
& $\frac{\pi}{2}$  \\ 
\hline
$\sin x$ & $0$  & $\frac{1}{2}$        & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ & 
$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $1$  \\
$\cos x$ & $1$  & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$        & $0$  \\
$\tan x$ & $0$  & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & $1$                  & $\sqrt{3}$           &   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How about `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.57}`? I'd also like to encourage you to be a bit more specific, i.e. to tell us what you wish to achieve. Otherwise there is a danger that this question could be closed as "primarly opinion based".

Comment: The booktabs package (and documentation) has some strongly held opinions about making tables pretty.  #1 is no vertical lines.  But I do agree with marmot that it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: It would also be helpful (for us casual readers) to include an image of the "ugly" table.

Comment: Typo: the second $\frac{\pi}{6}$ in the heading should be $\frac{\pi}{3}$. So far, all the answers have reproduced this error faithfully!

Comment: This might be tangential, but looking at the answers I have this great urge to nicely ask for filling the gap in place for `tan(pi/2)`. It almost looks like an erroneous omission.

Answer (score 12):

I'd keep it as simple as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering

\caption{Table of trigonometric functions for common angles}

$
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{12pt} % for this particular table
\begin{array}{@{} l *{5}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
  &  0 & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{4}      & \frac{\pi}{6} & \frac{\pi}{2}  \\ 
\midrule
\sin x
  & 0  & \frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1  \\
\addlinespace
\cos x
  & 1  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}        & 0  \\
\addlinespace
\tan x
  & 0  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & 1                  & \sqrt{3}           &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
$

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I use `array` to simplify the input (no `$` necessary except around the array). With `\addlinespace` we can easily separate the lines. With a larger value of `\arraycolsep` we better separate the columns for ease of reading in this particular case.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

my primary concern is to simplify your code. other is opinion based ...

- instead tabular i would use `array` and than remove all `$` in table code
- for more vertical space i would employ the `makecell` package, i.e. use its macro `\gapedcells`:
- note: `mathtools` load `amsmath`, so there is no need to load it again (loading packages more than once is not always innocuous...)

  ```
  \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  %\usepackage{gensymb}   % <--- do you really need?
  \usepackage{makecell}   % <--- new

  \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

  \begin{document}

  \[\setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
          & 0 & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{4}      & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      \hline
  \sin x  & 0 & \frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1      \\
  \cos x  & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}        & 0      \\
  \tan x  & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & 1                  & \sqrt{3}           & \infty \\
  \end{array}
  \]

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: This is by far the best looking table IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\def\getNum#1\relax{\gdef\num{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$}

\def\getDenum#1\\{\gdef\denum{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$&$\sqrt{\tfrac{\num}{\denum}}$\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{
    >{$}c<{^\circ$}
    >{\getNum}c
    >{\getDenum}c
    c
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\theta$}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin\theta$}&
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos\theta$}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan\theta$}\\
\midrule
0&
    0&
        4\\
30&
    1&
        3\\
45&
    2&
        2\\
60&
    3&
        1\\
90&
    4&
        0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

1. Use `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` from `booktabs` at the beginning and end of your table
2. Remove rules among columns and rows except the first one
3. Use `tabularx` with type `X` column instead of `tabular` (it is better since you force columns with similar contents to be of equal size, at least in my opinion)
4. Stretch your array `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}`
5. Use 'tab' to indent nested contents (this is to make debugging and revisions easier)

Code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

    \centering

    \begin{tabularx}{0.35\textwidth}{c| *{5}{C}} 
        \toprule
        &  $0$ & $\frac{\pi}{6}$      & $\frac{\pi}{4}$      & $\frac{\pi}{6}$      
        & $\frac{\pi}{2}$
        \\ 
        \hline
        $\sin x$ & $0$  & $\frac{1}{2}$        & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ & 
        $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $1$
        \\
        $\cos x$ & $1$  & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ & $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$        & $0$
        \\
        $\tan x$ & $0$  & $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ & $1$                  & $\sqrt{3}$           &
        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A workaround in `tabu`, an extension of `tabularx`; the most important thing to better presentations for fractions in math is to preserve the size of the numbers for this reason you must use `\dfrac` instead `\frac`; in the MWE some colors and rules modifications with `tabu`.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\tabulinesep=5pt
\tabulinestyle{1pt,blue}
\begin{tabu} to 0.5\linewidth {|X[c]|X[c]|[0.75pt]X[c]|[0.75pt]X[c]|[0.75pt]X[c]|[0.75pt]X[c]|}
\rowfont{\leavevmode\color{white}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
&\cellcolor{blue!30}$0$ 
&\cellcolor{blue!40}$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$
&\cellcolor{blue!50}$\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
&\cellcolor{blue!60}$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$      
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{blue!70}$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$}
\\ \tabucline -

%row2
$\sin x$
&$0$
&$\dfrac{1}{2}$
&$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
&$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
&$1$
\\[-0.5pt] \tabucline [0.5pt on 3pt blue] -

%row3
$\cos x$
&$1$
&$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
&$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
&$\dfrac{1}{2}$
&$0$
\\[-0.5pt] \tabucline [0.5pt on 3pt blue] -

%row4
$\tan x$
& $0$
& $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$
& $1$
& $\sqrt{3}$ 
&
\\ \tabucline -

\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: there is default `rowsep=2pt` with `tblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{tblr}{|c|ccccc|} 
\hline
         &  0 & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{4}      & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{2}  \\ 
\hline
  \sin x & 0  & \frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1  \\
  \cos x & 1  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}        & 0  \\
  \tan x & 0  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & 1                  & \sqrt{3}           &    \\
\hline
\end{tblr}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), the packages [bm](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm) and [cmbright](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmbright) and some light colours, are improvements:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm, cmbright, cals}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
%\everymath{\displaystyle}                                  % Nicest without displaystyle?

\begin{document}
\begin{calstable}[c]
\colwidths{{56pt}{33pt}{33pt}{33pt}{33pt}{33pt}} % 6 columns
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
    \def\cals@bgcolor{gray!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\green{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\blue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
    \def\cals@bgcolor{blue!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\black{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty
    \def\cals@bgcolor{black}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1
\brow
    \gray\alignC\cell{\vfil \textbf{Radians}}\gray
    \green\alignC\cell{\vfil $0$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\pi}{6}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\pi}{4}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\pi}{3}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\pi}{2}$}\green
    \ht\cals@current@row=33pt
\erow
% R3
\brow
    \blue\alignC\cell{\vfil \textbf{sin}($\bm{\theta}$)}\blue
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $0$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $1$}
    \ht\cals@current@row=33pt
\erow
% R4
\brow
    \blue\alignC\cell{\vfil \textbf{cos}($\bm{\theta}$)}\blue
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $1$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $0$}
    \ht\cals@current@row=33pt
\erow
% R5
\brow
    \blue\alignC\cell{\vfil \textbf{tan}($\bm{\theta}$)}\blue
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $0$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $1$}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil $\sqrt 3$}
    \black\alignC\cell{}\black
    \ht\cals@current@row=33pt
\erow\makeatother
\end{calstable}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, vous have a key `cell-space-limits`. Here the output with that key set to 3 pt.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{NiceArray}{|c|ccccc|}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
\hline
         &  0 & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{4}      & \frac{\pi}{6}      & \frac{\pi}{2}  \\ 
\hline
  \sin x & 0  & \frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 1  \\
  \cos x & 1  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}        & 0  \\
  \tan x & 0  & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} & 1                  & \sqrt{3}           &    \\
\hline
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]